# What other "shortcuts" but [Answer] does Code Review support?

Tags: discussion, comments

In [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173527/efficiency-of-a-linq-query-on-a-nested-structure#comment329156_173527) comment OP wanted to share some SQL and one of the tables was called `[Answer]` but it was turned into a link to the *How to Answer* page. I tried it myself and indeed this works. I've never seen this trick before. Are there more such shortcuts supported in comments or maybe even answers?

Comment: I've found `[faq], [help], [tour], [ask], [answer]` [faq], [help], [tour], [ask], [answer]

Comment: @Peilonrayz have you just tried some words or did you find an _offcial_ list? How about writing a brute-force script for finding them ;-)

Comment: @Peilonrayz there's another one `[chat]` [chat] and another one `[meta]` [meta] which interestingly does not work on meta :-]

Comment: ...and there's the `[edit]` [edit]

Comment: I just found some random words, and knew some of them. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a [list of them on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000). They are also known as '[magic-links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-links)'.

Some examples of these are [meta], [main] and [edit]. However, the above link doesn't contain them all. In [this meta.se question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183788), it shows that you can also use [faq#dontask], rather than [help/dont-ask], which comes up as [faq](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), rather than [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

In case you're wondering [codereview.se], works on other sites to link to us!

Comment: Another I'm particularly fond of is [help/on-topic] `[help/on-topic]`.